# Android state_selected no longer becomes rounded?

Tags: android

This selector used to work, but when I recently opened the project I noticed this UI bug where the selected state is no longer rounded. any thoughts?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_indicator_selected"
        android:state_selected="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_indicator_default"/>
</selector>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:innerRadius="0dp"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="2dp"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>


[![<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="5dp"
    android:useLevel="false">
    <solid android:color="@color/chuck_colorAccent"/>
</shape>
```

[image]